# how to change button width in layout inflater?

Tags: android, android-layout

i follow this tutorial http://karanbalkar.com/tag/dialog/ for layout inflater just tell me how do i change button width in  inflater sao button will full width  on inflater??

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/layouttimer">   

 <Button 
 android:id="@+id/start"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:text="Start Timer" > 
 </Button>   

 <Button 
 android:id="@+id/stop"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:text="Stop Timer" > 
 </Button>   

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/tv"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:text=""/>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i change button width"fill_parent" but is not change width

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` on your button.

You can try add this to button:

```
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Comment: i called this inflater in dailog